# Git: who else is making changes to same file

Tags: git

I am working in a git repository with multiple branches. For tracking some common files, I want to foresee the upcoming changes(Even before committed to master) in other branches.
As so many branches are there, I don't want to do a branch compare.

Is there any other way to track who else is making changes to a given file?

Thanks and Regards!!

Comment: Make people push their branches to a remote repo and you can watch those changes before they are merged to master. It doesn't help if you do not have a peer review process that also helps foresee those changes coming. If you are using GitHub or any of the likes, pull requests are a great collaborative tool. 

Drive by master commits are a pain if you don't see them coming. Ask 2Pac.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know who's changed the file until the file's been changed; that is, there has to be a record in Git that someone modified this file at some point in time.

The only record of that is on the remote server; they must publish their commits to it in order for you to identify what other changes had been made.

Comment: right, I think they mean seeing changes before merging into master.

the main issue is that a unified branch interface would just show a mess of merge conflicts.